# How to update data through Api in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core-webapi

I do the update command through the API. Everything seems fine. However, the data is not up to date. When I debug there is no error.

```
    public async Task UpdateViewRatingStore(bool value)
    {
        var url = baseUrl + userget;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", mytokenlogin);
        string jsonStr = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonStr);

        var checkunredrating = res.RatingStores;

        if (checkunredrating != null)
        {
            foreach (var r in checkunredrating)
            {
                r.ID = r.ID;
                r.StoreID = r.StoreID;
                r.RatingStores = r.RatingStores;
                r.CommentStore = r.CommentStore;
                r.UserRating = r.UserRating;
                r.CreateDay = r.CreateDay;
                r.Display = r.Display;
                r.ViewStorer = value;

                var urlput = baseUrlStoreRating + r.ID;
                var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res.RatingStores), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                await client.PutAsync(urlput, stringContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

However when I check in the database it is still not updated. I tested it manually on swagger and Posman was fine. Where did I go wrong? Ask for help. Thank you

Comment: you are serializing `res.RatingStores` and uploading it **inside** the loop.  Is that what you intend?  Or should you be uploading **just** the `r` that is being update inside the loop?

Comment: I mean every time `r` in the `foreach` loop will do data update by `r.ID` . My way is probably problematic, can you answer more clearly? Thank you

Comment: if you are only updating a single `r` but are passing the entire `RatingStores` that sounds like it will fail.  But I don't know anything about your API so I can't answer that question, only you can.  What does the PUT request expect as a payload?

Comment: I am having a `checkunredrating` list and I want to update the `ViewStorer=true` field in the `checkunredrating` list. So I run a loop to set `ViewStorer = true`. You know what I mean?

Comment: I can only assume that the PUT request expects to receive a single rating object, so you should send it just `r`, not the entire `RatingStores`.  Why don't you try that?  Or look at your API and verify what the expected payload is.

Comment: "I can only assume that the PUT request expects to receive a single rating object, so you should send it just r, not the entire RatingStores. Why don't you try that?" ---> Can you help me by submitting an answer to this problem? I've lost it all week but still can't solve it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to update a single object, but passing the entire collection every time

instead, try this

```
foreach (var r in checkunredrating)
{
    // you only need to update the changed values
    r.ViewStorer = value;

    var urlput = baseUrlStoreRating + r.ID;

    // only send the current object you are updating
    var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    await client.PutAsync(urlput, stringContent);
}
```

Comment: I have checked carefully. But the data is still not updated in the database, it also gives no error :(

Comment: have you debugged the server code to see how it is handling the request?  Or checked the server logs?  You have still not, despite several requests, provided any info about what the expected payload for this request is, so my answer is based on a best guess.