# Data not updating when PUT API in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have 1 question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017470/how-to-update-data-through-api-in-xamarin), thanks for your help I have solved the problem. Now I have the same problem thinking I did the right thing, however it is not so

Button Update

1. UserPage.xaml

   ```
   <controls:CustomEntry x:Name="txt_name" Text="{Binding CustomerGets.NameUs}"/>

   <controls:CustomEntry x:Name="txt_address" Text="{Binding CustomerGets.Address}"/>

   <Button x:Name="bt_updateuser" Clicked="bt_updateuser_Clicked" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Update">
   ```
2. UserPage.xaml.cs

   ```
   private async void bt_updateuser_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ....
       var url = baseUrl + userget;
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", mytokenlogin);
       string jsonStr = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

       var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonStr);

       res.NameUs = txt_name.Text;
       res.Address = txt_address.Text;
       ......

       var urlput = "xxxxx/api/Customers/" + userget;

       var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
       await client.PutAsync(urlput, stringContent);
   }
   ```

When I debug

[image]

I see the data in the received `res`, so why is it not updated. I tried on Posman, swagger it works

Where did I go wrong? Please help, thanks

Comment: what is the response code from the PUT?

Comment: You see this video but it is in Spanish. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQQuZ2st7n4&t=956s

Comment: You can first check the status code of the response.There should have some  relative logs about this problem.

Comment: Thank all, Looks like I'm wrong in the DateTime format in some field so it doesn't execute. I solved the problem